# How do I check whether a char is == to a number and why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, char, charat

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = console.nextInt();
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num);
        int max = 0;
        int cur = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
            char s = binary.charAt(i);
            if (s == 1) {
            cur += 1;
        } else {
            cur 0 ;
        }
        if (cur >= max) {
            max = cur;
        }
        }
    System.out.println(max);u
    }
}
```

It should return the number of consecutive "1"'s in a binary number. For example, if the input is 5, the number in binary is 101. Therefore, it would return 1. If the input was "6", the number in binary is 1100, so it would return 2. I think the s==1 line is the problem. Why?? Thanks in advance

Comment: The integer value for the character `'1'` is not equal to the integer value of `1`.

Comment: How do I get it to work exactly then?

Comment: java doesn't have javascript like type coercion

Comment: You parse your character and convert it to an integer.

Comment: I feel so stupid, thanks. I didn't know that char required that, we only learned Strings in class.

Comment: Compare `char`s to `char`s, e.g. `s == '1'`. Or look up the [integer value of the character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) you're interested, and compare that, e.g. `s == 31`.